# Ocelot always unauthorized with AuthenticationProviderKey

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, .net-6.0, ocelot

My problem ocelot gives only unauthorized erroru after adding AuthenticationProviderKey.
Ocelot file:

```
{
"Routes": [
  {
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/blog",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
      {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 7001
      }
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/gateway/blog",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
    "AuthenticationOptions": {
      "AuthenticationProviderKey": "TestKey",
      "AllowedScopes": []
    }
  },
  {
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/notfication",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
      {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 7011
      }
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/gateway/notfication",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post" ],
  },
  {
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
      {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 7021
      }
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/gateway/user",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post" ]
  },
  {
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/auth",
    "DownstreamScheme": "https",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
      {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 7031
      }
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/gateway/auth",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ],
  }
],
```

"GlobalConfiguration": {
"BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7000"
}
}

APIGateway Program.cs

```
    string authenticationProviderKey = "TestKey";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
    //option => {
    //    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = authenticationProviderKey;
    //    option.DefaultScheme = authenticationProviderKey;
    //    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = authenticationProviderKey;
    //}
    )
    .AddJwtBearer(authenticationProviderKey, options =>
     {
         options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             IssuerSigningKey = signInKey,
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
             RequireExpirationTime = true
         };
     });

builder.Services.AddOcelot();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
 
.
.
.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
await app.UseOcelot();
```

İt is not give unauthorized error when I delete AuthenticationProviderKey located in the ocelot. Let me note that there are no problems with other services. Because he does not apply there. There is a problem with ApiGateway API.
**What's wrong ?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem ocelot gives always unauthorized erroru after adding AuthenticationProviderKey.

Comment: do you solved problem?

Comment: @xxxsenatorxxx Yes. The problem was in the latest version of Ocelot. I used the previous version